# WebdriverIO : Junit report- How do I generate the junit report under specify directory

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm trying to integerate Junit reporter in my webdriverio project

junit config in wdio.conf.js

[image]

When I execute the report generates in my terminal output but the xml file is not generated under the junitreports directory.

Terminal output

[image]

[image]

Can you please help me overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to generate the XML report using the below configuration in the wdio file:

```
reporters: [['junit',{
            outputDir: './Reports/junit-report/',
            outputFileFormat: function(options) { // optional
                return 'junit-report.xml'
        }
    }]
],
```